# CNN with 0.995 accuracy does not perform well in implementation

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook, conv-neural-network

To keep it short, I have trained a model on a binary classification with equal data in each class so as to not have class imbalance. The model is trained on 10 000 images with the respective labels and validated on 6 000 images with the respective labels.

The result is a model with 0.995 accuracy which should mean that implementation of the model will classify the correct classes 0.995 of the time. (Model is NOT choosing class A all the time and being correct 0.995 of the time because there is no class imbalance)

However, this is not the case. Also, the data has been shuffled so the model is also not guessing class A for the first 5000 images and then guessing class B for the rest to get 0.995 accuracy.

The full code, question and things I took note of is on my github:

https://github.com/Nickclickflick/tutorials

Feel free to download and use the model so as to see the results of the flappy bird bot.

---

Edit 1: 8 000 of the total images are original and the other 8 000 are augmented as described below

The following code snippet shows the augmentation to the original images

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(featurewise_center=True, samplewise_center=True, 
                             featurewise_std_normalization=True, samplewise_std_normalization=True, 
                             zca_whitening=True, zca_epsilon=1e-06)
```

Edit 2: The following code was used to generate the original dataset (this is available on github)

```
import numpy as np
from grabscreen import grab_screen
import cv2
import time
from getkeys import key_check
import os

jump = [1,0]
do_nothing = [0,1]

starting_value = 1

while True:
    file_name = 'E:/flappy/tmp_data/training_data-{}.npy'.format(starting_value)

    if os.path.isfile(file_name):
        print('File exists, moving along',starting_value)
        starting_value += 1
    else:
        print('File does not exist, starting fresh!',starting_value)

        break


def keys_to_output(keys):
    output = [0,0]

    if ' ' in keys:
        output = jump
    else:
        output = do_nothing
    return output


def main(file_name, starting_value):
    file_name = file_name
    starting_value = starting_value
    training_data = []

    # countdown
    for i in list(range(6))[::-1]:
        print(i+1)
        time.sleep(1)

    paused = False
    print('STARTING!!!')

    while True:

        if not paused:
            screen = grab_screen(region=(0,200,600,1000))
            last_time = time.time()

            # resize to something a bit more acceptable for a CNN
            screen = cv2.resize(screen, (150,250))
            # run a color convert:
            screen = cv2.cvtColor(screen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)    

            keys = key_check()
            output = keys_to_output(keys)
            training_data.append([screen,output])


            if len(training_data) % 10 == 0:
                print(len(training_data))

                if len(training_data) == 100:
                    np.save(file_name,training_data)
                    print('SAVED')
                    training_data = []
                    starting_value += 1
                    file_name = 'E:/flappy/tmp_data/training_data-{}.npy'.format(starting_value)


        keys = key_check()

        # pause script
        if 'T' in keys:
            if paused:
                paused = False
                print('unpaused!')
                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                print('Pausing!')
                paused = True
                time.sleep(1)


main(file_name, starting_value)
```

Comment: So taking a quick look at your code, you're classifying frames from the Flappy Bird game as either jump or do nothing.  Your ultimate goal is to use this classifier as part of a Flappy Bird playing bot.  The classifier performs well on the validation dataset, but the bot performs poorly playing the game, is that correct?  How does the bot play badly?  Does it try to classify each individual frame?  If so, then I would wager that while your training dataset is balanced, the underlying distribution is not which could result in the bot jumping too much.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Also, how exactly did your generate your dataset?  That's very important to how the model and bot will perform in "production".

Comment: @Syrius I was not sure why the bot was performing poorly despite having high accuracy and balanced dataset, however after Kyle Parsons comment, I think the problem lies in the classification of 1 frame vs a few frames.  Right now I am wondering if the bot will be able to work properly after I apply LSTM so as to classify a few frames at a time instead of the individual frames at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three things named accuracy, Precision, and recall. Accuracy is generally not the preferred performance measure for classifiers, especially when you are dealing with skewed datasets (i.e., when some classes are much more frequent than others).

Precision:

```
    TP
_________
TP  +  FP
```

Recall:

```
    TP
_________
TP  +  FN
```

where,
TP=True positives

FP=False negatives

A much better way to evaluate the performance of a classifier is to look at the confusion matrix. The general idea is to count the number of times instances of class A are classified as class B.To compute the confusion matrix, you first need to have a set of predictions, so they can be compared to the actual targets.

[image: An illustrated confusion matrix for digit 5 classifier.]

you can use the cross_val_predict() function from scikitkearn library to compute the predicted targets.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
y_train_pred = cross_val_predict(sgd_clf, X_train, y_train_5, cv=3)
```

Now you are ready to get the confusion matrix using the confusion_matrix() function.
Just pass it the target classes (y_train_5) and the predicted classes (y_train_pred):

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
confusion_matrix(y_train_5, y_train_pred)
```

Scikit-Learn provides several functions to compute classifier metrics, including precision and recall:

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, recall_score

precision_score(y_train_5, y_train_pred)
recall_score(y_train_5, y_train_pred)
```

Hope this helps:)

Comment: Thank you for replying I think I'll work on that now and consider this question as answered.

Comment: If you think that this is the answer to your question please do accept the answer. This gives me some motivation to contribute something to the community :)

Comment: You can learn more about it  [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-data-science-classification-metrics-in-scikit-learn-in-python-3bc336865019)